# Java remote debugging, eclipse can't stay connected

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I have an issue when I try to remote debug via eclipse.

These are the arguments I use:

```
-Xdebug
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4044
```

I also tried setting the address to 0.0.0.0:4044, using this:

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4044
```

I have tried all sorts of setups, setting suspend to 'y' made the application wait for a debug connection, as soon as it got connected the application continued but a connection couldn't be made.

When I try to connect from eclipse it just times out.

If I run a `netstat -tulpn | grep 4044` I get this output:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4044                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

After the connection attempt sometimes it stops listening on the port.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Normally on the listening process I use:

-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4044,server=y,suspend=n

You have to start the process correctly
E.g. for tomcat

```
    JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n"
    catalina.sh jpda start
```

using a wrapper as tanuki:

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-java-detect-debug-jvm.html

If you read it

> The Wrapper has several features which are designed to detect when a
>   JVM has frozen, or otherwise become unstable. Normally these features
>   should all be left enabled. However, when a JVM is connected to a
>   debugger, it is common for the JVM to intentionally be frozen as
>   various debugging operations take place. In these cases, the Wrapper
>   would normally think the JVM was frozen, and kill and restart it in
>   the middle of a debug session. The Wrapper works around this problem
>   by checking the configured Java command line and ignoring certain
>   timeouts when it detects that a debugger is in use. This property
>   makes it possible to enable or disable this debugging check. The
>   default value is "TRUE", which will detect the debugging and ignore
>   certain timeouts. Example: (detect the debugging)
>   wrapper.java.detect_debug_jvm=TRUE

(...)

In your case I think you just need

```
    wrapper.java.detect_debug_jvm=FALSE
```

Let me know if I am right cause I cannot test it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! We use a wrapper (Tanuki) to start our application, don't really know how that would work. Plus in the past I think remote debugging has worked fine.

Comment: i edit the reply. I don't know tanuki but from the doc I think I can give a solution

Comment: I had a quick glance at the documentation as well but no luck! I'll give that a try, will let you know! Thanks!

Comment: Did u try the wrapper.java.detect_debug_jvm=FALSE.  It should work.

Comment: Didn't work, as soon as I click on my run configuration the server "stops" something that's running on my debug port

Comment: Try also:  wrapper.java.command=jdb or one of the wrapper.java.additional.<n> properties to "-Xdebug". And combinations?

Comment: Yes, the -Xdebug is in my wrapper.conf

Comment: then I can think only: what is tanuki wrapping. it is probably there that you miss the right configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I needed to debug in on OSGI server.

There were a combination of trouble and after solving them I could debug well.

I answered it  [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937828/how-to-allow-remote-conection-with-karaf-for-doing-remote-debugging)

By the way, you can try by stopping your firewall, in case of iptables you have to do:

```
service iptables stop
```

You can try by modifying your debugging port and trying to access it. Another test you can do is to debug with another tool like [JDebugTool](http://www.debugtools.com/) to check if you Eclipse is the problem.

If you use Ant, verify you have your javac configured well:

```
<javac srcdir="..." destdir="..." classpathref="..." debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" />
```

In Eclipse verify you have this:

```
windows > preferences > Java > compiler -> "Classfile generation" -> check "Add line number attributes to generated class file"
```

Hope to help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following in the ntServiceWrapper.conf worked for me

```
wrapper.java.detect_debug_jvm=TRUE

# Number of seconds to allow between the wrapper pinging the JVM and the response.
wrapper.ping.timeout=0
```