# How to allow remote conection with Karaf (for doing remote debugging)?

Tags: java, remote-debugging, apache-karaf

I need some help.

I have a vmware virtual machine with a Karaf server and some java applications deployed. I've started karaf with debug flag and it opened port 5005 for debugging.

What I want to do is connect to this port with eclipse to do remote debugging, but I am always refused to connect.

I can access to the virtual from an external firefox using the VM IP, but when I enter the karaf port 8181 I'm not able to connect.

Do you know how to enable Karaf to accept remote connections?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Which Karaf debug flag are you passing?  Can you paste the entire command line of your JVM?

Comment: Hi Sbodd, I'm using:
bin/karaf debug

Comment: did you check the firewall settings? Is the VM configured for Bridged Network, cause you might just don't get a connection to the machine, it's most likely not an issue with Karaf itself since you can't reach any port remotely.

Comment: Hi Achim, yes I thought the same. I set VM in Bridged Network. By the way, if I put the vm ip in firefox I can see a screen to my CentOS (my vm OS).

Comment: Can you connect to the Karaf container if you run JDB locally on the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the troubles, it was a combination of things.

First of all, I used **Bridged Network** in the VM-Ware configuration.

I started karaf with debug flag. It has enabled port **5005** for debugging. It is:

```
bin/karaf debug
```

My pom.xml was configured with debugger flags. Like:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<configuration>
  ...
  <!-- Necessary in order for the debug levels to be considered-->
  <debug>true</debug>
  <debugLevel>lines,vars,source</debugLevel>
</configuration>
```

And the last thing, I had to stop the firewall. In my case was iptables, doing the following:

```
service iptables stop
```

Doing all above steps allows me to perform java remote debugging successfully.

Thanks all for the comments.