# Remote Debugging Eclipse : Failed to connect to remote VM

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug an application remotely.
While configuring i am giving Standard(**Socket Attach**) Connection type.

After when I debug it I got following exception.

```
com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.ClosedConnectionException
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService.readHandshake(SocketTransportService.java:209)
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService.access$7(SocketTransportService.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService$3.run(SocketTransportService.java:172)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What can be the possible reason of it?

Comment: Did you set the JVM debug options?

Comment: Make sure that you have configured the port you are accessing through Eclipse on the server side and the server knows that it's meant for debugging connections. Also make sure that the port is open when you try to connect (e.g. not used by something else or someone else trying to debug the application besides you)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I needed to debug in on OSGI server.

There were a combination of trouble and after solving them I could debug well.

I answered it  [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937828/how-to-allow-remote-conection-with-karaf-for-doing-remote-debugging)

By the way, you can try by stopping your firewall, in case of iptables you have to do:

```
service iptables stop
```

You can try by modifying your debugging port and trying to access it. Another test you can do is to debug with another tool like [JDebugTool](http://www.debugtools.com/) to check if you Eclipse is the problem.

If you use Ant, verify you have your javac configured well:

```
<javac srcdir="..." destdir="..." classpathref="..." debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" />
```

In Eclipse verify you have this:

```
windows > preferences > Java > compiler -> "Classfile generation" -> check "Add line number attributes to generated class file"
```

Hope to help